# Create admin role in MongoDB and login

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, compass

**Hi!**

So, I'm making a Node.js application and this site supposed to have one single admin. The site has no registration. I'm using Mongoose and MongodDB.
For this I'm thinking to create the admin from MongoDB using Compass.
I have an admin model with email and passport but I don't really know how to approach the problem.
I also have trouble to find a passport localstrategy to login the admin.

Can you help me to solve this?
Thanks!